# How durable is Natsu Dragneel?

Tags: fairy-tail

I've only seen part of the first season of Fairy Tail (up to the end of the lullaby flute battle with the Erigor and that Dark Guild). More specifically, I'm on the episode right after when Natsu and Happy steal the job for the cursed island off the upstairs board at the guild hall.

In the past battle over the Daybreak book, Natsu fought a pair of mercenaries who said that wizards spend so much time harnessing their minds that their bodies are weak, which is their weakness, but after fighting Natsu and his dragon-slayer magic they saw how powerful he was physically.

Exactly how durable is Natsu? Does it scale specifically off of how much fire he has absorbed? Or is his body just naturally tough from training directly under a dragon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well throughout the series the mercenaries have been proven wrong in just about every fight, no matter the wizard. I'm not sure what makes Natsu so durable, but it seems like every wizard can take a beating magically and physically, most likely based on how much magic power they have (my best guess at least). When you see more fights you will notice that those mercenaries appear to be very misinformed about how most wizards fight.

Comment: Alrighty, guess I just gotta watch more of the anime and add the manga to my read list

Comment: Its duely notable that most Dragonslayers Are all about phsyical combat. Many of their attacks are enhanced punches or kicks of some kind, or at least use their arms or legs as a tool to guide the attack. Many magics are like that in the FT universe. Most end up just being another sword or shield, or a tool to increase the effectiveness of that sword or shield. Even fights also tend to last a long time, So the ability to defend yourself and absorb damage is pretty important. Besides all that, we do follow the most powerful guild, so its expected they are strong.